# Webcrawler for Testing und learn

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Hi I wanted to try to program a crawler.

I started with a very simple code but already when I execute it I get an error message.

What is wrong with the code?

I geht this Error at the source point.

```
Exception has occurred: ConnectTimeout
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.anisearch.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /anime/2788,naruto (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002757873E090>, 'Connection to www.anisearch.de timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Ein Verbindungsversuch ist fehlgeschlagen, da die Gegenstelle nach einer bestimmten Zeitspanne nicht richtig reagiert hat, oder die hergestellte Verbindung war fehlerhaft, da der verbundene Host nicht reagiert hat

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002757873E090>, 'Connection to www.anisearch.de timed out. (connect timeout=None)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.anisearch.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /anime/2788,naruto (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002757873E090>, 'Connection to www.anisearch.de timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Crawler\anisearch_crawler.py", line 5, in <module>
    source = requests.get(url)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.anisearch.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /anime/2788,naruto (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002757873E090>, 'Connection to www.anisearch.de timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))
```

It is clear to me that he cannot reach the page, but I do not understand why.
Here my Easy Code

```
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.anisearch.de/anime/2788,naruto"
source = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')

def info_anime(soup):
    # Extracting the name of the anime from the <meta> tag
    anime_name = soup.find('meta', {'name': 'title'})['content']
    print("Anime : " + anime_name)


info_anime(soup)`
```

debug with vs code but i am not really unterstood in what case are the problem. It say "can not request" but why and how i solfe this problem that i can geht this information back.

The site has no api so i try with this methode

Comment: either the site is/was down or they have blocked your IP address when they detected you tried to scrape the site.

Comment: What is the solution against theme? I have only made a request nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using [`HTMLSession`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) instead of `requests` - that worked for me.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = "https://www.anisearch.de/anime/2788,naruto"
source = HTMLSession().get(url)
# source.raise_for_status() ## good habit in general

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')
```

[image: op]

Comment: Thx for the help but it still not work for me

maybe to try with a user Agent like this?

`headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'
}
source = HTMLSession().get(url, headers=headers)`

Comment: @D1skanime does it work for you then? I usually use HTMLSession bc I'm not good with headers, but it doesn't work 100%

Comment: No it doesn't work for me, that's why I ask if it works for you with header.
Are there other possibilities?

Must possibly try with a porxy that I start directly from python? Or what other possibilities are there?